# IE7 z-index wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bu8qx/).

In IE7 the code in the jsFiddle above displays the dropdown `(.sbOptions)` under the next selectbox element `(.sbHolder)`.

`.sbOptions` has `z-index: 100;` but is still displayed under `.sbHolder`.

This works fine in all browsers except IE7, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Just asking... Why you support IE7?

Comment: For z-index to work in older IE, the elements need to be position absolute or relative, they need to have content etc. and still it can be a pain in the ass to get it working.

Comment: @czachor Some clients still need support for IE7, even Microsoft supports IE6 till april 2014... http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: Hm... it seems that jsFiddle doesn't work in IE7...? Anyway, check this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-ie-z-index/

Comment: @czachor that solution will not work for me because it's a huuuuge site and this will only cause other problems. Also I need a fix that is only for IE7.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in IE7: **Without setting z-index** and as long as hasLayout is set to true, a **stacking context is assigned** to a positioned element. Width and height of .sbHolder are such hasLayout triggers. Therefore, the second .sbHolder is at the top.

IE7 changes your rule to:

```
.sbHolder {
    position: relative;
    width: 130px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 0; /* ! */
}
```

This ruins your plan to increase .sbOptions z-index since .sbOptions is catched by the irregular stacking context of .sbHolder.

I've got a solution for IE <=7 in that only one .sbOptions is dropped down at the time. Does this come up to scratch? Let's hope so!

Have a go: http://jsfiddle.net/HRubx/

The irregular stacking context is now produced if required:

```
li:hover {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to keep adding Z-index 1 in IE7 to even start getting jsfiddle to work.

Have you tried the ole zoom:auto in places? Put that into the css.

Also, z-index and absolute would seem almost at odds... absolute pulls the element out of document flow so there is no 'real' z-index different from another that is pulled out.

Perhaps trying different positioning schemes..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/) article.

In short, it uses jquery to sort the z-index by changing other elements:

> One way to fix many of the issues with IE7 is to dynamically reverse the default z-index stacking order of the elements on your page. This will ensure the elements higher in your HTML source will also have a higher z-index order on your page, solving most of the IE stacking issues.

```
$(function() {
    var zIndexNumber = 1000;
    $('div').each(function() {
        $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
        zIndexNumber -= 10;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey bro if you can't change your mark-up alot, just add z-index in the parent's div like above:

```
<div class="sbHolder" style="z-index:11">
    <a href="#" class="sbToggle"></a>
    <a href="#" class="sbSelector">1</a>

    <ul class="sbOptions">
         <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sbHolder" style="z-index:10">
    <a href="#" class="sbToggle"></a>
    <a href="#" class="sbSelector">A</a>

    <ul class="sbOptions">
        <li><a href="#1">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#4">D</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```